# cypher option to return nodes as json objects?

Tags: rest, neo4j, cypher

I am using the Cypher ReST API. It returns 1 object with two name value pairs "columns" and "data".  Is there a way to ditch the columns and have the nodes returned as objects instead of an array of arrays? More in line with this: http://bl.ocks.org/4062045#miserables.json

Here is what I get now:

```
curl -d @query --header "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher
{
  "columns" : [ "source", "r_type", "target" ],
  "data" : [ [ "Corn", "LIKES", "Parsley" ], [ "Corn", "LIKES", "Sunflowers" ], 
[ "Corn", "LIKES", "Pumpkin" ], [ "Corn", "LIKES", "Peas" ], [ "Corn", "LIKES", "Beans" ], 
[ "Corn", "HATES", "Tomato" ], [ null, null, null ], [ "Carrots", "LIKES", "Tomato" ], 
[ "Carrots", "LIKES", "Peas" ], [ "Carrots", "LIKES", "Onions" ], ....
```

the query file:

```
{
  "query" : "start n  = node(*) match n -[r?]-> m return n.name? as source, type(r) as r_type, m.name? as target",
  "params" : {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a [server plugin](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-plugins.html) to achieve this.  It would then be available via the REST API.

Comment: Not bad.  the plugin architecture is more straight forward than I would have thought.  We'll see.  I still might just opt to post-process.